# Fetch in React Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm getting this error on a fetch in React:

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I have already found that the issue is that fetch is adding http://localhost:3000/ to the beginning of the url request and I do not know why.

This is my fetch:

```
export function getRecipes(ingredients, dish) {
    const url = `www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish}`;
    console.log(url)
        return dispatch => {
            //dispatch(setRecipesRequest());
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => {
                  console.log('recipes', json);
                  setRecipes(json);
                });
        }

}
```

Even though I have specified the url, this is the request URL that the Network tab displays on google chrome:

http://localhost:3000/www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=asdasd&q=asdasd

And I need it to be:

www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=asdasd&q=asdasd

Comment: have you tried http:// www. ?

Comment: I ll give it a try...1 sec

Comment: Genius answer! Thanks a lot Sthepen

Comment: no problem, ill add it as the answer :) edit: feel free to mark the answer I provided as correct if you feel its correct.

Comment: For sure it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a external request, you need to define the protocol, otherwise it will be relevant to your domain.

Adding http/s to the start of the request should solve your issue

`const url = http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=${ingredients}&q=${dish};`

Example from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```